# Swift, Xcode - Open ViewController only once per use

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

My intention is to add a tutorial to my app, which is supposed to show only once per user.

So far my approach has been to create a `func` which is being called when `viewDidLoad`:

```
func checkInitialVc() {
        firstTime = defaults.bool(forKey: "firstTime")

        if firstTime {
            let initialData = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController") as! ViewController
            self.show(initialData, sender: initialData)
        }
    }
```

The problem is that as I open the App, even tho it's the first time, nothing happens.

`firstTime` is declared global:

```
var firstTime: Bool = false
```

In the ViewController which is to be opened, but doesn't, I've got:

```
@IBAction func buttonStart(_ sender: UIButton) {
        firstTime = false
        defaults.set(firstTime, forKey: "firstTime")
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToSecond", sender: self)

    }
```

Comment: Do you ever wrote `true` for `"firstTime"` into the defaults? You probably don't, `firstTime` will ALWAYS be `false`.

Comment: @luk2302 No, could you please illustrate what I've to add in an answer?

Comment: Example here: https://github.com/mattneub/RegistrationExample In that example, the thing that is to be opened only the first time is a "registration screen", not a tutorial, but the basic principle and underlying mechanism is _exactly_ the same — the RegistrationViewController is opened only once per user (once the user has done the requisite task).

Answer (score 1):

Another way is changing semantics of the bool retrieved from user defaults, for example from `firstTime` to `tutorialShown` since if the key doesn't exist user defaults will return `false`.

```
func checkInitialVc() {
        tutorialShown = defaults.bool(forKey: "tutorialShown")

        if !tutorialShown {
            let initialData = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController") as! ViewController
            self.show(initialData, sender: initialData)
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you start the application it loads every swift file including your boolean.
So in this case the steps it takes are:

```swift
var firstTime: Bool = False  // Everytime you startup -> false
class YourViewController: UIViewController {
  override func viewDidload(){
    checkInitialVc()
  }

  func checkInitialVc() {
    firstTime = defaults.bool(forKey: "firstTime")
    if firstTime { // is False so never enters brackets
      let initialData =  self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController") as! ViewController
       self.show(initialData, sender: initialData)
    }
  }
}
```

So just try setting the global `Bool` as a UserDefault so that when you load the app it already has the value that will be set with your button after the view has loaded and the button has been pressed:

```
var firstTime = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "firstTime")
class YourViewController: UIViewController {
  override func viewDidload(){
    checkInitialVc() //calls your function when view is available
  }

  func checkInitialVc() {
    if !UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey:"firstTime"){ // UserDefaults.standard.bool is by default false

    let initialData = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController") as! ViewController

    self.show(initialData, sender: initialData)
  }

  @IBAction func buttonStart(_ sender: UIButton) {
    UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "firstTime")
    /* 
    or     
    */
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToSecond", sender: self)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The use of a global is wrong. Change

```
func checkInitialVc() {
    firstTime = defaults.bool(forKey: "firstTime")
    if firstTime {
        let initialData = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController") as! ViewController
        self.show(initialData, sender: initialData)
    }
}
```

To:

```
func checkInitialVc() {
    UserDefaults.standard.register(defaults:["firstTime":true]) // <--
    firstTime = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "firstTime")
    if firstTime {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(false, forKey: "firstTime") // <--
        let initialData = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController") as! ViewController
        self.show(initialData, sender: initialData)
    }
}
```